# How to see how much space is being used per domain/directory even?

Tags: ssh, disk-space-utilization

My client is using up to 300GB of disk space across three subdomains. Is there an easy way to see what is being used? For example, I would be able to see each subdomain and the size they are taking, and even each directory inside the subdomains? using ssh, or opensource application?

Comment: What OS? Also, the wording suggests you are talking about a web server but you really need to be clear about such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux box?

du -csh /path/to/directory

Comment: great. how do i show the measurement in gb?

Comment: The -h should make it "human readable"..  Just look for the G and M next to the directory names.

Answer (score 0):

For a detailed set of directory usage, I like to use:

```
du -x /path/to/top/directory | sort -rn | less
```

This will show the use of each directory (and all it's sub-contents), sorted with the largest at the top.  The "-x" option is useful if the proc, sys, or other virtual file-systems are mounted (say you are running a du of the root directory).

For example, my 1.5GB /var has use like:

```
1572347     /var
1161430     /var/lib
1049414     /var/lib/pgsql
1049412     /var/lib/pgsql/data
934120      /var/lib/pgsql/data/base
857420      /var/lib/pgsql/data/base/16398
214904      /var/cache
188599      /var/cache/yum/i386/14
188599      /var/cache/yum/i386
188599      /var/cache/yum
```

Ah, I see it's time to do a "yum clean all".  :-)